# TextView animation and remove

Tags: android

When I swipe right on a TextView, I want to start the animation and remove it, but the TextView is being removed without the animation. Any ideas on how to fix this, and why this would not work? Thank you.

```
public void onSwipeRight() {
    textview.animate().translationX(500).alpha(0).setDuration(150).start();
    linearlayout.removeView(textview);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the animation to complete before you remove the view:

```
textview.animate()
    .translationX(500)
    .alpha(0)
    .setDuration(150)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            linearlayout.removeView(textview);
        }
    })
    .start();
```

**Note:** Since `alpha(int)` is `deprecated` you need to use:

```
textview.animate()
    .translationX(500)
    .alpha(0f) //float value
    .setDuration(150)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            linearlayout.removeView(textview);
        }
    })
    .start();
```